# Ways to send data between server and android client?

Tags: android, c, sockets

Hy everybody,

I'm looking for a way to send data between a server- and a android (client) application. The target is to realise a little chat (just for fun) between multiple android devices.

I thought about those ways:

1. I create a socket from the client and send the IP and ID to the server. The server knows now the clients IP adress. So if I like to send some data I can reopen the socket from the server to the client. Every time the client changes his IP it has to send the new IP to the server.
2. I create a socket and let it the hole time open. I dont like this one, because I need to create for every client a thread on the server.

Is there another way? How would you do it?
Thanks for your answer =)

Comment: Don't reopen the socket for every message. Multithreading is totaly fine. Another way would be: http://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/

Comment: use thread pool for better performance, some thread for accepting connection, some thread are worker to translate message and blah blah. and some thread for sending message to clients

Comment: `I can reopen the socket from the server to the client. ` No that is not possible.

Comment: No I didn't want to reopen it... Just create a new one ;) Sorry I wrote it wrong.

Comment: Also realise that a server cannot open/create a connection to a client.

Comment: Yeah I've got that. Thanks =) I found a really good article for a multithreaded work queue server in c++ : http://vichargrave.com/multithreaded-work-queue-based-server-2/